# Rownumberer is growinp up together with columns

Tags: extjs

I'm developing a application using Ext Js and I have a problem, in one of my views the user is able to add new columns dinamically, and in grid the first Ext component is a rownumberer, which enumerate my rows as the user are added it. However as the rows are being added, the fisrt column which is 'rownumberer' is growing up together, as shown below.
Can anyone provide me a insight? Thanks!

[image]

The code:

```
var store = Ext.getStore('store');
var rowEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing');
var contador = 0;
Ext.define('Grid', {
extend : 'Ext.grid.Panel',
title: 'Grid',
store: 'StoreTemp',
columns: [ 
    {
     xtype: 'rownumberer'
 },{    
     header : "Data Type",
     dataIndex : 'nome',
     flex : 0.8,
     editor:'textfield'
 }],            
dockedItems : [ {
xtype : 'toolbar',
items : [ {
    xtype: 'button',
    tooltip: 'Click here to set data type on axis Y',
    id : 'buttonTipoDado',
    icon : Webapp.icon('edit.png'),
    iconAlign : 'top',
    handler : function() {
        var gridView = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('gridpanel')[1];
        Ext.Msg.prompt('Alert', 'Insert data type: ', function(
                btn, text) {
            if (btn == 'ok') {
                gridView.getView().getHeaderAtIndex(1).setText(text);
                var botao = Ext.getCmp('buttonTipoDado');
                botao.setDisabled(true);
            } else {
                Ext.Msg.alert('Alert', 'Insert type!');
            }
            gridView.getView().refresh();
        });
    }
}, {
    xtype: 'button'
    icon : Webapp.icon('add1.png'),
    iconAlign : 'top',
    handler : function() {
        var gridView = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('gridpanel')[1];
        grid = gridView.headerCt;
        if(grid.getGridColumns().length >= 1){
            var column = Ext.create('Ext.grid.column.Column', {text : contador, editor: {xtype: 'textfield', flex: 0.5}});
            gridView.headerCt.insert(gridView.columns.length, column);
            var botao = Ext.getCmp('buttonRemoverColuna');
            botao.setDisabled(false);
        }
        contador++;
    }
}, {
    xtype: 'button',
    icon : Webapp.icon('cancel.png'),
    iconAlign : 'top',
    id : 'buttonRemoverColuna',
    handler : function() {
        var gridView = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('gridpanel')[1];
        gridView = gridView.headerCt;
        var botao = Ext.getCmp('buttonRemoverColuna');
        if(gridView.getGridColumns().length == 2){
            botao.setDisabled(true);    
            contador = 0;
        }
        else{
            gridView = gridView.remove(gridView.getGridColumns().length - 1);               
        }
    }
}, {
    xtype: 'button',
    icon : Webapp.icon('add1.png'),
    iconAlign : 'top',
    handler: function(){
        var gridView = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('gridpanel')[1];
        grid = gridView.getView();
        grid.insert(0, new Ext.create('Model'));
        rowEditing.startEdit(0, 0); 
        gridView.getView().refresh();
    }   
}, {
    xtype: 'button'
    icon : Webapp.icon('cancel.png'),
    iconAlign : 'top',
    handler: function(){
        store.removeAt(0);
    }   
}]
} ],
plugins : [ rowEditing ]

});
```

Comment: Which version of ExtJS are you using? Does this only occur when you have a roweditor open? Can we see your gridpanel code?

Comment: My code is shown below, thanks.

Comment: You should edit your question and include the code in the question, rather than as an answer.

Comment: Ok, I'm beginner here, it will not happen again, thanks.

Comment: No worries, you still can fix it if you would like to. Just click the edit button above, add the code to the question and then delete that answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your `Data Type` column `flex` config. You should change that to `flex: 1` instead.

The `rownumberer` column has a default `width: 23` config so you do not need to specify an exact width on that.